# How to configure SockJsHttpRequestHandler using XML in a working application

Tags: spring, configuration, messaging

From spring-websocket-portfolio-master WebConfig.java:

```
@Bean
public SimpleUrlHandlerMapping handlerMapping() {

    DefaultSockJsService sockJsService = new DefaultSockJsService(sockJsTaskScheduler());
    //sockJsService.setDummySessionCookieEnabled(true);
    HttpRequestHandler requestHandler = new SockJsHttpRequestHandler(sockJsService, stompWebSocketHandler());

    SimpleUrlHandlerMapping hm = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
    hm.setOrder(-1);
    hm.setUrlMap(Collections.singletonMap("/portfolio/**", requestHandler));
    return hm;
}
```

I want to add to XML configuration in current application.  I have the following in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mximonitor</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mximonitor</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I have this so far (and I hope it is right):

```
<!-- Following two beans were wrapped in a SimpleUrlHandlerMapping bean -->    
<bean id="sockJsService" class="org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.DefaultSockJsService">
  <constructor-arg index="0" ref="sockJSTaskScheduler"/>    
</bean>

<bean id="sockJsHttpRequestHandler" class="org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.SockJsHttpRequestHandler">
  <constructor-arg index="0" ref="sockJsService"/>
  <constructor-arg index="1" ref="stompWebSocketHandler"/>    
</bean>
```

I would like to be able to add new request handler to existing configuration.  I guess I would use 'SimpleUrlHandlerMapping' but I am fairly new to Spring (and web programming in general).  How would I configure?  Is 'SimpleUrlHandlerMapping' additive (meaning it will not interfere with existing controllers?

Thanks in advance (and for your patience),

James